# What does "toast" mean?

Tags: android, toast, android-toast

Curious what "Toast" means?

Saw this and am curious...

### Similar Posts

- [How to add toast style popup to my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461184/toast-style-popup-for-my-application)
- [Program to show a "toast" notification popup from the Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844192/program-to-show-a-toast-notification-popup-from-the-windows-command-line)
- [Why does my text keep highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344855/why-does-my-text-keep-highlighting)
- [Thread-safe Form.Show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787023/c-thread-safe-form-show)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686886/c-remoting-with-forms
- [Using Jabber to send network messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950371/using-jabber-to-send-network-messages)
- [Android: determining the current context to display an alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774545/android-determining-the-current-context-to-display-an-alert)
- [.NET AnimateWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493293/net-animatewindow)
- [Android toast blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618587/android-toast-blur)
- [Can an Android Toast be longer than Toast.LENGTH_LONG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220560/can-an-android-toast-be-longer-than-toast-length-long)
- [Why does my text keep highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344855/why-does-my-text-keep-highlighting)

Comment: Want the complete source of my project?

Comment: I would have named this thing "whack-a-mole" myself.

Comment: wow I've never actually heard this term before somehow... how odd :)

Comment: What an informational thread.  I didn't even know those things had a name.

Comment: That's the first I've heard that, too.

Comment: mmm....toast...

Comment: I thought these were called "Flash Messages?"  (from Ruby on Rails)

Comment: This makes me unreasonably happy.  Thanks for asking

Comment: 11.5 years later and I'm still toasting vis-à-vis ngx-toastr. Waiting for ngx-airfryer though.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

A small informational message that pops up like toast.

[image]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toast_(computing)

Comment: Learn something new every day...that's indeed the official name? Must be when it's referenced in the Wikipedia ;)

Answer (score 28):

It's a type of Window that "pops up" like toast:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632289%28VS.85%29.aspx
>
> An example of a Messenger toast is the message that appears on a user's desktop when one of the user's contacts signs in. Another example of Messenger toasts is the messages displayed when a user receives an alert from the .NET Alerts service. The following are examples of typical toasts:
>
> [image]   [image]

Answer (score 28):

"Toast" refers to a UI feature where an event causes a small text box to appear at the bottom of the screen.  The behavior seems like a piece of bread emerging from a toaster.

Answer (score 11):

It is a popup alert that generally appears on the right hand side of the screen, and is usually for notifications with great importance. There is generally a cool effect with it, such as fading or stretching.

In my question, the toast pops up and fades in.

Answer (score 6):

Toast is just another name for a [pop-up notification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop-up_notification), a small message that appears temporarily to communicate some information. Pop-ups referred to as “toast” are usually displayed at the bottom of the screen, and in some cases actually pop up like toast:

[image: Message saved as draft.]

Photo above from [Android Developers: Toasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

Answer (score -2):

Its a kind of notification that is poped up.

Comment: The notification is Catholic? ;)