# Proper way to call AnimateWindow with a .NET WinForms Form?

Tags: winforms, animatewindow

i'm trying to call [`AnimateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to animate the show and hide of a WinForms window.

Here's a copy of [the win32 translation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/FormAnimation.aspx):

```
private static class NativeMethods
{
   public const int AW_ACTIVATE = 0x20000;
   public const int AW_HIDE = 0x10000;
   public const int AW_BLEND = 0x80000;
   public const int AW_CENTER = 0x00000010;
   public const int AW_SLIDE = 0X40000;
   public const int AW_HOR_POSITIVE = 0x1;
   public const int AW_HOR_NEGATIVE = 0X2;

   [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
   public static extern int AnimateWindow(IntPtr hwand, int dwTime, int dwFlags);
}
```

But the problem is how to fit a call to [`AnimateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) into the) WinForms scheme. [One person suggests](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/FadePage.aspx) **OnLoad**:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    AnimateWindow(this.Handle, 200, AW_ACTIVATE | AW_HOR_NEGATIVE | AW_SLIDE);
}
```

and **OnClosing**:

```
protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosing(e);
    if (e.Cancel == false)
    {
        AnimateWindow(this.Handle, 200, AW_HIDE | AW_HOR_POSITIVE | AW_SLIDE);
    }
}
```

Except that it doesn't work.

- the form doesn't use any animation while appearing
- during hide the form animates its horizontal slide off the screen, then reappears, before hiding the normal way

What is the **correct** way to mix [`AnimateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with WinForms?

---

### See also

- [.NET AnimateWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493293/net-animatewindow): this guy asked the same question. But since it was trying to achieve something else, people solved his problem rather than answering his question.
- [C# WinForms AnimateWindow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669496/c-sharp-winforms-animatewindow-issue): This guy was interested in using `AnimateWindow` with child controls, rather than a top-level window.

---

### Bonus Chatter

i was [perusing](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) through the `Form -> Show -> Visible -> SetVisibleCore`, when i discovered this bug:

```
protected virtual void SetVisibleCore(bool value)
{
   try
   {
      HandleCollector.SuspendCollect();
      //...snip...
   }  
   finally
   {
      HandleCollector.ResumeCollect();
   }
}
```

Nice to know that everyone can introduce these subtle errors.

Answer (score 3):

I *think* `AnimateWindow` has it's limitations to work properly.  For example, it doesn't play well with Aero, so to animate a sliding form, you would need to set the `BorderStyle` to None.  Also, make sure the `StartPosition` is set to Manual.

Simple example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

  public const int AW_ACTIVATE = 0x20000;
  public const int AW_HIDE = 0x10000;
  public const int AW_BLEND = 0x80000;
  public const int AW_CENTER = 0x00000010;
  public const int AW_SLIDE = 0X40000;
  public const int AW_HOR_POSITIVE = 0x1;
  public const int AW_HOR_NEGATIVE = 0X2;

  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  public static extern int AnimateWindow(IntPtr hwand, int dwTime, int dwFlags);

  public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Form toastForm = new Form();
    toastForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    toastForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    toastForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    toastForm.Size = new Size(256, 64);
    toastForm.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Right - toastForm.Width, 
                                   Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom - toastForm.Height);

    Button closeButton = new Button();
    closeButton.Text = "Close";
    toastForm.Controls.Add(closeButton);
    closeButton.Click += delegate { toastForm.Close(); };

    AnimateWindow(toastForm.Handle, 200, AW_ACTIVATE | AW_HOR_NEGATIVE | AW_SLIDE);
    toastForm.Show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Blast; i'm not dealing with a "toast" window; but a full-fledged maximized window.

Comment: @IanBoyd Winforms isn't going to like that.

Comment: I'm curious what API's Microsoft uses by default to do the minimize animations considering this AnimateWindow has so many issues.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what your [`AnimateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call does, but when you need to change underlying native 'stuff' to do with windows forms, I've always used the CreateParams() override. You may 
find a similar function for what you are trying to achieve.

Here's an example of a transparent tool window, that doesn't activate when it is shown.

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
        Get
            Dim baseParams As Windows.Forms.CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams

            baseParams.ExStyle = baseParams.ExStyle Or NativeMethods.ExtendedWindowsStyles.WS_EX_LAYERED Or NativeMethods.ExtendedWindowsStyles.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT Or NativeMethods.ExtendedWindowsStyles.WS_EX_NOACTIVATE Or NativeMethods.ExtendedWindowsStyles.WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW

            Return baseParams
        End Get
    End Property
```