# Set Toast Appear Length

Tags: android, time, toast

Is there anyway I can tell a Toast Notification to show up only for a specified amount of time.  Generally shorter then a regular toast message.

Comment: I have developed a custom Toast class with which you can show Toast for a specified amount of time... have a look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220560/can-an-android-toast-be-longer-than-toast-length-long/21203554#21203554

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I found a solution to this by calling toast.cancel() after a certain delay that is shorter than the standard toast duration.

```
        final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ctx, "This message will disappear in 1 second", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   toast.cancel(); 
               }
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: its not working 2nd time when i change value to 100 instead of 1000 because i need it to display toast for very short duration...

Comment: @Aniket, maybe it's too fast you can't see it?

Answer (score 6):

No.

You can do something like:

```
Toast a = Toast.makeText(this, "a", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
a.setDuration(300);
```

but it will not show itself.

The duration should be either `LENGTH_SHORT` or `LENGTH_LONG`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "YOUR MESSAGE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000)
            {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {toast.show();}
                public void onFinish() {toast.cancel();}
            }.start();
```

Hope this help.. Enjoy..!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can set a longer duration by using a hack, as described [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/19/indefinite-toast-hack/)

Answer (score 0):

//try it

```
    public void myToast(String message) {
    LayoutInflater myInflator = getLayoutInflater();
    View myLayout = myInflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toastlayout));
    TextView myMessage = (TextView) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.label);
    myMessage.setText(message);
    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    toast.setView(myLayout);
    toast.setDuration(400);
    myMessage.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
            | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    toast.show();
}
```

Comment: I don't think this does anything for extending the duration.  If the duration is not either LENGTH_SHORT or LENGTH_LONG, it defaults to LENGTH_LONG.  This method accepts arbitrary values in nature, but in reality, only changes the behavior (toast length) if the value is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

The stock Android Toast class is coded to accept only a Toast.LENGTH_SHORT or Toast.LENGTH_LONG parameter when calling a Toast. The values of these parameters are 0 and 1 respectively and do not accept any millisecond value when calling setDuration(); If you must show a Toast for a different duration than you may consider using a class from my [SuperToasts](https://github.com/JohnPersano/SuperToasts) library. The [SuperToast](https://github.com/JohnPersano/Supertoasts/wiki/SuperToast) class in the library is a mimic of the stock Android Toast class and can have any millisecond value used as a duration parameter. I do not recommend using this class to show a Toast **longer** than the maximum stock Android Toast length due to the lingering effect of these Toasts. I recommend that you use the [SuperActivityToast](https://github.com/JohnPersano/Supertoasts/wiki/SuperActivityToast) class to show Toast messages in an Activity/Fragment because the Toast will be destroyed along with your Activity eliminating any chance of a lingering message. To use this class you may create a new object:

```
SuperActivityToast superActivityToast = new SuperActivityToast(this);  
superActivityToast.setDuration(SuperToast.DURATION_SHORT); 
// setDuration(); can also accept millisecond values
// superActivityToast.setDuration(1000);  
superActivityToast.setText("Hello world!");  
superActivityToast.show();
```

Or use the static method:

```
SuperActivityToast.createDarkSuperActivityToast(this, "Hello world!", SuperToast.DURATION_SHORT).show();
```

There are tons of customization options you can use with the library as well, check out the [Wiki](https://github.com/JohnPersano/Supertoasts/wiki) page!

Answer (score -1):

Here is another way to configure the time per your choice:

```
public void showMsg(String msg, final long duration) {
    final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run(){
            try {
                sleep(duration);
                toast.cancel(); 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally { }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

NOTE: The duration is specified in milliseconds.