# android custom toast duration

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can an Android Toast be longer than “Toast.LENGTH_LONG”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220560/can-an-android-toast-be-longer-than-toast-length-long)

Is it possible to make a Toast with custom duration (8 or 26 seconds)? I've read questions [Set Toast Appear Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775074/set-toast-appear-length) and [Can an Android Toast be longer than Toast.LENGTH_LONG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220560/can-an-android-toast-be-longer-than-toast-length-long) but none of those questions received a working answer.

Comment: Asking the question again wont make something that was not-possible suddenly possible :). Again thats not what toast was designed to do. There are other popup's that you can use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to make a Toast with custom duration (8 or 26 seconds)?

No, which is exactly the response in the two questions you linked to.

> I've read questions Set Toast Appear Length and Can an Android Toast be longer than "Toast.LENGTH_LONG"? but none of those questions received a working answer.

That is because (as both links point out) it is not possible, so there is no "working answer".  The answers do suggest alternatives for you to consider.