# How to set Toast display time less than Toast.LENGTH_SHORT

Tags: android, toast

I want to display toast less than Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, as i feel its taking around 2 seconds. i want to display toast only for half second.

And what is time interval for Toast.LENGTH_SHORT and Toast.LENGTH_LONG ?

Comment: It looks like you can't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220560/can-an-android-toast-be-longer-than-toast-length-long

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Toast Appear Length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775074/set-toast-appear-length)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are only two possible values:

```
private static final int LONG_DELAY = 3500; // 3.5 seconds
private static final int SHORT_DELAY = 2000; // 2 seconds
```

Setting other values doesn't work. If duration not equals 1 (`Toast.LENGTH_LONG`), then duration will be SHORT_DELAY (2 seconds):

```
long delay = immediate ? 0 : (r.duration == Toast.LENGTH_LONG ? LONG_DELAY : SHORT_DELAY);
```

In sources of `Toast` written that

> This time could be user-definable.

but I can't find way to do this.

**Update:** There is solution here: [Set Toast Appear Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775074/set-toast-appear-length/9715422#9715422)

Comment: I think that implies user-definable by the user of the device. Not the developer.

Comment: I am afraid, bt it might be incorrect @Sergey Glotov to say that one cant do it. The code mentioned by Emran Hamza very well works.

Comment: @SergeyGlotov Not an issue :)

Answer (score 33):

This has worked for me

```
final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The following message will disappear in half second", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

    Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               toast.cancel(); 
           }
    }, 500);
```

Answer (score 10):

See my suggested solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9715422/1250735). You basically call toast.cancel() after a specified delay that is shorter than the standard toast duration.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "YOUR MESSAGE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000)
            {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {toast.show();}
                public void onFinish() {toast.cancel();}
            }.start();
```

Hope this help.. Enjoy..!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
public void showMyToast(final Toast toast, final int delay) {
    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            toast.show();
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            toast.cancel();
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }, delay);
}
```

//how to use(MainActivity.this is example ,it could be changed by yourself)
 and (In showMyToast(first param ,second param) method, second parameter is time what u really defined like 
 this)

```
Toast toast=Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MyToast Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            showMyToast(toast, 1000);
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49111992/edit) your answer to explain why this piece of code answers the question.

Comment: This is a method , I will add how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

it will work.

---

```
   public void toastMessage(final String message) {
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            LayoutInflater myInflator = getLayoutInflater();
            View myLayout = myInflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,
                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toastlayout));
            TextView myMessage = (TextView) myLayout
                    .findViewById(R.id.label);
            myMessage.setText(message);
            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setView(myLayout);
            toast.setDuration(100);
            myMessage.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
                    | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For noobs I've made the simplest solution - a method.

```
public void showToastMessage(String text, int duration){
        final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                toast.cancel();
            }
        }, duration);
}
```

You should also import:

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

You can call this method for example:

```
showToastMessage("your noob", 1000);
```

**method above should work only in Fragment! If you want it to work in Activity, replace *getActivity()* with *getApplicationContext()* in toast message. Good luck developers!**

Answer (score -4):

This seems to work for me (set the duration to whatever you want):

```
mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast toast = new Toast(mActivity
                                .getApplicationContext());
                        toast.setView(layout);
                        toast.setDuration(400);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Did you try it? It does not wokt at all!

Comment: Yes, when I tried it it worked, or I though it did. The accepted answer seems to be that its impossible. Its been a long time since I wrote this. I was using Android 2.2 at the time.