# How to custom Toast's display time in Android?

Tags: android, toast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set Toast Appear Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775074/set-toast-appear-length)

In Android,there are only two elements to control toast's time: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT and Toast.LENGTH_LONG.But I want to let the Toast display only 0.5 seconds or less.How can I do?Who can help me? Very thanks!

Comment: Toast doesn't support this. Check the following answer for the details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6095362/648313. You may however try the following hack: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9715422/648313

Comment: I have developed a custom Toast class with which you can show Toast for a specified amount of time... have a look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220560/can-an-android-toast-be-longer-than-toast-length-long/21203554#21203554

Answer (score 8):

The values of [`LENGTH_SHORT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#LENGTH_SHORT) and [`LENGTH_LONG`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#LENGTH_LONG) are 0 and 1.  This means they are treated as flags rather than actual durations so I don't think it will be possible to set the duration to anything other than these values.

If you want to display a message to the user for longer, consider a [Status Bar Notification](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).  Status Bar Notifications can be programmatically cancelled when they are no longer relevant.

But this is not end you can do like this

```
for (int i=0; i < 2; i++)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "blah", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

to double the time. If you specify 3 instead the 2 it will triple the time..etc.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` or `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` with `500`

Comment: It doesn't work like this. You would need to do what Drawable mentioned above.