# Toast message length

Tags: android, toast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can an Android Toast be longer than “Toast.LENGTH_LONG”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220560/can-an-android-toast-be-longer-than-toast-length-long)

Is there a way to make Toast messages last longer than Toast.LENGTH_LONG.  I don't feel this length of time is quite long enough for the user to read the notification I'm displaying.

Comment: I am afraid not by definition of Toast.makeText(). But if your message is such intense, I think you should consider other means like Notification or so.

Comment: Take a look at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220560/can-an-android-toast-be-longer-than-toast-length-long

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Check the answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220560/can-an-android-toast-be-longer-than-toast-length-long

Comment: I see.  My intention here is to show a little help message when the user visits a screen for the first time.  I don't think a status bar notification will meeting these needs.  It needs to look nice and pop up on the screen much like a Toast message.  Do you have any other suggestions for built-in notifications that I might utilize?  Or am I looking at building my own?

Comment: I'm intending to show the user a little help message the first time they visit the screen.  I don't think status bar notifications will suffice here.  Is there something else like Toast I can use?  Or am I looking at building my own popup?

Comment: @Andrew, try show an AlertDialog.

Comment: Create a Dialog, and then start a timer. You can dismiss it after any length of time.

Comment: I agree. An AlertDialog would probably be the best bet. You could probably also add a timer that automatically closes the dialog after a certain period of time.

Comment: Or you can use a little hack as described [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/19/indefinite-toast-hack/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this kind of messages there is the `Dialog` class. Actually to be more precise the [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) class. A help text should be visible to the user as long as the user needs that help message.

You should also take a look at the [Creating Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) article on the developers site.