# What is the value of Toast.LENGTH_LONG and Toast.LENGTH_SHORT?

Tags: android, time, toast, short, android-toast

I am printing Toast message in my application to show notification but i want to know value of 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG and Toast.LENGTH_SHORT.
What other values i can use.

Can anyone tell me what is the value of these two variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220560/can-an-android-toast-be-longer-than-toast-length-long

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is another question that answers what you are looking for.  The answers are:

```
private static final int LONG_DELAY = 3500; // 3.5 seconds
private static final int SHORT_DELAY = 2000; // 2 seconds
```

This was courtesy of FeelGood. You can find the whole thread below.

[Can an Android Toast be longer than Toast.LENGTH_LONG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220560/can-an-android-toast-be-longer-than-toast-length-long)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Reference - 
https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java#L381-L382

Answer (score 4):

There are only these two constants related to Toast

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#LENGTH_LONG

Why would you want to know their values though? You should always use the constants instead.

Comment: He's probably thinking he can set the duration to an arbitrary number of milliseconds.  He cannot.

Comment: @Earl : yes I want to show toast for some arbitrary time.Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

They are one and zero as detailed in the [Toast documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html). They are the only two values and no others are possible.  There is an "indefinite toast hack", but I would not use an application that used it.

Answer (score 1):

**LENGTH_SHORT & LENGTH_LONG are mapped to time interval of 1 Second (1000mS) & 5 Seconds (5000mS) respectively,**

To see this you need to dig into the AOSP source code of `Toast`. You can see in the Toast class time interval is decided based on the FLAG

```
mParams.hideTimeoutMilliseconds = mDuration == Toast.LENGTH_LONG ? LONG_DURATION_TIMEOUT : SHORT_DURATION_TIMEOUT;
```

where

```
 static final long SHORT_DURATION_TIMEOUT = 5000;
  static final long LONG_DURATION_TIMEOUT = 1000;
```

Reference:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/f4bed684c939b0f8809ef404b8609fe4ef849263/core/java/android/widget/Toast.java

Comment: Wrong reference. 
The actual values are here https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java#L381-L382