# Alert dialog period is to short

Tags: android, alert, android-alertdialog, period

I have an alert dialog which is invoked when the user click back button on device but this alert is too short and the user cant read anything inside it or do any thing with it..

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(birthDate.this).create();
                    // Setting Dialog Title
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");
                    // Setting Dialog Message
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Welcome to AndroidHive.info");
                    // Setting OK Button
                    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
```

***I want to make the period of this alert dialog longer***

Comment: you mean the period of the toast or the alertDialog ? because the alertdialog will not dismiss with your code here , ( you didn't call dismiss() method ) ,  and for the toast, you can specify the param of duration to 10000 ms ( 10 seconds ) for example

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220560/can-an-android-toast-be-longer-than-toast-length-long

Comment: Can you explain Weather you are talking about Alert Dialog or Toast?

Comment: @Android Developer: check my answer

Comment: What actually you want to show on press of back button... onBackPressed()... make sure you do you processing before calling super.onbackPressed()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are calling alertdialog and `finish()` both are at same time. Try to finish the activity in the alert dialog as

```
alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();// here calling finish if user click ok button.
                }
```

Comment: It not relevant answer. How it possible to doing both at a time..It can not be.

Comment: both at time means calling alert dialog function and below of it calling finish() will cause display alert dialog and immediately finish() will call so that activity move on..

Comment: That will cause Window Leak exception and application will crash

Comment: call dismiss() instead of finish(). finish() will kill the activity, and dismiss() will just dismiss the dialog

Answer (score 1):

My answer refer to your point **I want to make the period of this alert dialog longer**

```
long time=System.currentTimeMillis();
Show Dialog
```

When **dismissing** dialog then again `long time2=System.currentTimeMillis();` So `time2-time1` is your required time

**Updated**

You are saying AlertDialog dismiss on back press button of device then make **AlertDialog** cancel-able false.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that here you are asking about the `Toast` which is getting displayed on click of alert dialog button. You can do that by increasing the duration of `Toast` to be appeared. Just replace `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` by whatever duration(in milliseconds) 
you want.

Ex.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", 5000).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. This will give you enough time to show your Alert dialog. I've give 3 seconds by giving 3000 as the parameter, you can change according to your requirement.

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Title of your message!");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Your message to user");
    alertDialog.show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }, 3000);

}
```