# controling the displaying time of a toast

Tags: android, android-toast

I used **toasts** in my **android** application. Can I show the **toast** as long as i wish instead of

```
Toast.LENGTH_LONG
```

and

```
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
```

can someone help me with some helpful code segment. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503727/how-can-i-show-a-toast-for-a-specific-duration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is create a method which with some kind of looping around to make your Toast display as long as duration you want it,

```
private void showToast(int duration) {
    final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                                                      "This is a Toast Message!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    new CountDownTimer(duration, 500) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                toast.show();
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                toast.cancel();
            }

        }.start();
    }
```

And then you can call this method as `showToast(10000);`. So, what it will do is it will keep showing the Toast in loop until the duration and will cancel the toast as the duration is completed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "YOUR MESSAGE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000)
            {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {toast.show();}
                public void onFinish() {toast.cancel();}
            }.start();
```

Enjoy..

Comment: are you sure it will appear for 10 seconds? I don't think so :-)

Comment: Yes..It will appear for 10 secs

Comment: @Lalit Please try edited answer.. Its working

Comment: Perhaps you meant `tag.cancel()` inside `onFinish()`?

Comment: Yes your right.. apologies for mistake... Also if it is working u can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

no cannot directly handle that,you have to use handler to cancel the toast like this:

```
 final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This message will disappear         in half second", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();

Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           toast.cancel(); 
       }
}, 500); // 500ms is the time to cancel the toast.
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer OP's question...

Comment: While this code is working, it still probably won't help OP because he wants to have longer duration instead.