# can't change duration in Custom Toast

Tags: android, duration, android-toast

I have a `Custom Toast` which i want it to be display for 10 seconds

this is my code:

```
                        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
                                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

                        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
                        text.setText("please wait.... ");
                        text.setTypeface(type);

                        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                        toast.setDuration(10000);
                        toast.setView(layout);
                        toast.show();
```

but it doesn't work by setting `toast.setDuration(10000);` 
is anyone know what is wrong in my code or how can i do this in another way?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503727/how-can-i-show-a-toast-for-a-specific-duration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503727/how-can-i-show-a-toast-for-a-specific-duration)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Toast have only two variants to go as you already know

```
private static final int LONG_DELAY = 3500; // 3.5 seconds
private static final int SHORT_DELAY = 2000; // 2 seconds
```

anyway the link in the comments points to the right answer, noticed that later