# timer in toast android

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to make a simple countdown timer that shows the remaining time in a toast.
I wrote this code:

```
new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long timeRemaining) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + timeRemaining / 1000, 
                                                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        // do something
    }

}.start();
```

The problem is that the action that's in the onFinish method is executed when in the toast I'm showing "3".
So, the toast is slower respect the timer.
How can I solve that?

Comment: i would suggest you to use a textview to display time remaining instead of toast.

Comment: I need to use the toast.

Comment: If you are trying to show a countdown to the user then Toast produces an unpleasant user experience for that.  You could use a Dialog or DialogFragment instead, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Toast** shouldn't be used that way. **Toast.LENGTH_SHORT** will remain there for 3 seconds before disappearing, however timer will tick every second so obviously Toast is slow.

If you want to show timer to user then you must use a **TextView**, if you want timer for your own then you can use `Log.d();`

Update :- After a bit searching I found out that you cannot set Toast for custom time. The Toast has only two values Toast.LENGTH_LONG and Toast.LENGTH_SHORT. See this question here [Can an Android Toast be longer than Toast.LENGTH_LONG?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2220560/1979347). As a work around,if you really want to set the Toast for just 1 second, then you can do this

```
final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ctx, "This message will disappear in 1 second", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   toast.cancel(); 
               }
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: And you could not set the duration of a second to toast so that it stays in step with the timer?

Comment: You can just use 1000 in place of Toast.LENGTH_SHORT

Comment: the timer is always faster respect at the toast

Comment: @GiovanniMariotti some FYI for you, please upvote answers that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The Android OS queues Toasts if they appear in rapid succession. So what happens is that there is a slow delay between the actual tick and the toast fade away. This means that for many ticks, the toasts start to lag behind. A simple fix would be to reduce the number of Toasts.

Answer (score 0):

**onFinish -> toast.cancel()**

```
  
  final Toast showToast = Toast.makeText(this, "test ya!!! i'm Strtoint", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 

     // Set the countdown 
     CountDownTimer toastCountDown = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) //if set 1sec ->1000 ms
     {
            public void onTick(long timeRemaining) {
              showToast.show();
            }
            public void onFinish() {
              showtoast.cancel();
            }
     };

      // Show the toast and starts the countdown
      showToast.show();
      toastCountDown.start();
     }
```