# Toast not displaying before audiorecord

Tags: android, onclick, toast, audiorecord, android-toast

I would like to display a toast While there are background audiorecord tasks running.

Right now I have something like this which displays a toast with an image in it just fine:

```
...onCreate(){
        mHandler = new Handler();

//Toast Setup
        LayoutInflater myInflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View view=myInflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,null);
        mytoast=new Toast(this);
        mytoast.setView(view);
        mytoast.setGravity(0, 1, 1);
        mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}


//HANDLER STUFF
     final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            mytoast.show();
        }
        };

... onClick(){
audiorecordingtasks();
mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);

}
```

However, if I put mHandler.post(mUpdateResults); before my audiorecord tasks it waits until after the audiorecord task to finish before it displays it.

Anyone know how to display it before and DURING the audiorecord task?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

Here look there is the answer....

[Can an Android Toast be longer than Toast.LENGTH_LONG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220560/can-an-android-toast-be-longer-than-toast-length-long)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though I don't know if I need all that.  I'm just looking to display a sign that says yes it's actively recording now with the toast seemed to be the easiest way.  The handler was just playing around getting used to it.

I just want to know how to get the toast fixed for now so it shows before audiorecordingtasks();

Comment: why do you use complex toast just for using to display string thats says "RECORDING"?? if you only display string use the toast like this `Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show;`

Comment: No, It's still doesn't show while the audiorecord task is running.

Answer (score 0):

You should access the toast methods in a static way such as this:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "TExt i want to display", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```