# Set Android Toast duration to be really long (e.g., 1 minute)

Tags: android, toast, duration

I try to set my Toast show duration like 1minute.
I try this:

```
  final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MESSAGE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG );
  toast.show();

    Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   toast.cancel(); 
                   }
            }, 60000);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since LENGTH_SHORT is 2 seconds (and LENGTH_LONG is 3.5 seconds), try this:

```
for (int i=0; i < 30; i++)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "MESSAGE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: This solution might blink.

Answer (score 4):

There are only two possible `Toast` durations: short (2 sec) and long (3.5 sec).

If you need a more persistent message, use a dialog or include the message in your layout.

One easy way to make context-sensitive messages in your layout with custom durations is the [Crouton library](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220560/can-an-android-toast-be-longer-than-toast-length-long).

> The values of `LENGTH_SHORT` and `LENGTH_LONG` are 0 and 1. This means they are treated as flags rather than actual durations so I don't think it will be possible to set the duration to anything other than these values.

Answer (score 1):

```
final Toast tag = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "YOUR MESSAGE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

tag.show();

new CountDownTimer(9000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {tag.show();}
    public void onFinish() {tag.show();}

}.start();
```

See [Similar Question and answer there.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7173248/318938)

Answer (score 0):

Toasts are not meant to be used like that. Toasts are transient and Android has defined them to be either SHORT or LONG.

If you want, you can create a Dialog than completely emulated the appearance of a Toast, but I would use a dismissable dialog or a notification as it could be frustrating for the user to have a Toast showing for a whole minute without the possibility to dismiss it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show toast by your choice you have to make a custom toast with time duartion that you want

```
                View toastview = findViewById(R.id.customtoastlayout);
                LinearLayout mToastLayout = 
                toastview.findViewById(R.id.toastlayout);
                TextView text = toastview.findViewById(R.id.customToastText);
                text.setText(message);
                Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT, 90, 0);
                toast.setDuration(duration);//custom duartion
                toast.setView(mToastLayout);
                toast.show();
```