# Showing a Toast Message for 30 seconds

Tags: android, android-toast

Is there a way to show a Toast message for 30 seconds (without the blinking effect)?

I have already tried the methods on this post, however none of them works for me (Android 9)

[Can an Android Toast be longer than Toast.LENGTH_LONG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220560/can-an-android-toast-be-longer-than-toast-length-long)

On top, I can't use the Snackbar or Statusbar Notification feature for my situation

Comment: did you try this https://blog.cindypotvin.com/toast-specific-duration-android/ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Android Toast duration to be really long (e.g., 1 minute)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134640/set-android-toast-duration-to-be-really-long-e-g-1-minute)

Comment: [Custom toast on Android: a simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288475/custom-toast-on-android-a-simple-example/30411107)

Comment: Yep, already tried all those methods, as it seems Google has changed some things during the last years

Answer (score 0):

you can use [SuperToast](https://github.com/JohnPersano/Supertoasts/wiki/SuperActivityToast) for showing toast to user

of other way you can show a dialog box non cancelable and put it in a thread in 30 sec dismiss it but you must handle views and context and this is so hard job

you can try this code maybe work for you :

```
private Toast mToastToShow;
public void showToast(View view) {
   // Set the toast and duration
   int toastDurationInMilliSeconds = 10000;
   mToastToShow = Toast.makeText(this, "Hello world, I am a toast.", 
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

   // Set the countdown to display the toast
   CountDownTimer toastCountDown;
   toastCountDown = new CountDownTimer(toastDurationInMilliSeconds, 
                                   1000 /*Tick duration*/) {
      public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mToastToShow.show();
      }
      public void onFinish() {
         mToastToShow.cancel();
         }
   };

   // Show the toast and starts the countdown
   mToastToShow.show();
   toastCountDown.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are!

```
private Toast mToastToShow;
    public void showToast(View view) {
       // Set the toast and duration
       int toastDurationInMilliSeconds = 10000;
       mToastToShow = Toast.makeText(this, "Hello world, I am a toast.",                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

       // Set the countdown to display the toast
       CountDownTimer toastCountDown;
       toastCountDown = new CountDownTimer(toastDurationInMilliSeconds, 1000 /*Tick duration*/) {
          public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             mToastToShow.show();
          }
          public void onFinish() {
             mToastToShow.cancel();
             }
       };

       // Show the toast and starts the countdown
       mToastToShow.show();
       toastCountDown.start();
    }
```

Comment: Already tested that one and didn't work (at least for me on Android 9) does this work for you? If so, on which Android Version?

Comment: I am currently running  on Android 10 and it's working fine. Try using Snackbar like here https://mobikul.com/how-to-make-customizable-snack-bar-in-android/

Comment: Is the toast blinking or staying persisten for 10 seconds?

Comment: It is persisten.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

**No**

Detailed answer:

You cannot make **Toast** with custom duration, based on [official documentations](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)):

> Duration: How long to display the message. Either LENGTH_SHORT or LENGTH_LONG Value is LENGTH_SHORT, or LENGTH_LONG

Any alternative?

In your case you can use alert dialog, popup window or third party libraries such as [KoushikToast](https://github.com/koushikDeb/KoushikToast).

Notice that if you want to use [KoushikToast](https://github.com/koushikDeb/KoushikToast) or any other library, you need to add `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission in your manifest and also grant it manually or [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39406719/3892248) on API 23 and higher.