# How to make toast visible for long time?

Tags: android, toast

I want to know how to display toast programmaticaly. When I read the data from the database, I can only see the toast for short time, even though the length of the text is small or bigger. But I want to see the toast visible for little longer(At least for 3-5 seconds).

Comment: This may help u.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220560/can-an-android-toast-be-longer-than-toast-length-long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might suit your needs :

```
String stringFromDatabase = "your string";

if (stringFromDatabase.length()<200){
    Toast.make(context, stringFromDatabase, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
    Toast.make(context, stringFromDatabase, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This will show your Toast for a short or long time, depending on the length of your String.

Comment: it looks great, even though, my string is bigger it will show for just little longer, but i have to make it visible until user has to read it. Note: I can't say length of the text

Comment: If you want to have more control over the time the text is presented to the user, then it's not a Toast you need. Have a look at the question linked by Vigneshearan.m.

Answer (score 1):

Toast is displayed as below.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), textToDisplay, 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The parameter Toast.LENGTH_LONG tells that it should display for long. May be u need to change it to LENGTH_LONG.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement a custom Toast if you want to display the message for longer time. The values of LENGTH_SHORT and LENGTH_LONG are 0 and 1. They don't specify an amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the longest time a toast can be displayed is 3.5 seconds(for LENGTH_LONG, while LENGTH_SHORT is 2 seconds).

If you want a shorter toast you can cancel it after a pause - for example:

```
final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your string", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            toast.cancel();
        }
    }, 500);
```

Will display for 500 ms.

For a longer message you have to display few toasts one after the other, or choose a different method to convey your message