# How to display Android toast for longer time

Tags: android, android-toast

I am new in android, I want see my message in a `Toast` but it shows to for a little time.

I want to show the message for example until one hour or more.

Comment: Use AlertDialog for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an Android Toast be longer than "Toast.LENGTH\_LONG"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220560/can-an-android-toast-be-longer-than-toast-length-long)

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. Use a Custom Dialog and dismiss it when you want. But i wonder why do you want to display some kind of pop up for such a long time.

I would suggest re-considering your design.

You may also want to check Crouton

https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Dialog box instead of toast

```
SingleButtton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // Creating alert Dialog with one Button

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogActivity.this).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Welcome to Android Application");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) 
                    {
                        // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed

                    }
                });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The values of `LENGTH_SHORT and LENGTH_LONG` are `0 and 1`.they are treated as flags therefore  I  think it is not  possible to set time other than this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

**Edit:**

```
int time  = 1000*60 // 1 hour
for (int i=0; i < time; i++)
{
  Toast.makeText(this, "Your msg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

Comment: `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` is the max. cannot exceed that

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work like that. Refer to wqrahd`s answer for explanation.

Comment: It's a small trick by this you can achieve some short of thing you want. Try to change for loop condition it will work. I tried and it was working for me.

Comment: @GulMuhammadAkbari why do you want it. I don't see the need and re-think your design

Answer (score 0):

Well, like said here, there is no proper way to do this.

But, there is a sort of hack to it - just run your Toast in a `for-loop`, and the amount of iterations will control the length. For example - running the loop twice (like below) will double the time. Running it 3 times will triple the length. Again, it is just a work-around that works :-)

```
for (int i=0; i < 2; i++)
{
      Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

You must take into account that it does have flaws - it the user quits the app before the end of loop it will continue to show, and, on some devices the Toast might flicker between each iteration. So, up to you!

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of toast is showing a simple message in a time. You can't show it for long time. you can customized your own UI for Toast messages using dialog.

```
public static void showCustomToast(final Activity mActivity,final String helpText,final int sec) {
  if(mActivity != null){
 mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 @Override
    public void run() {
        int mSec = 3000;
        if(sec != 0){
           mSec = sec;
  }
  LayoutInflater inflater = mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
  View messageDialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay_message, null);
  layer = new CustomLayout(mActivity);
  LayoutParams params = new                                                LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  messageDialog.setLayoutParams(params);
  TextView message = (TextView) messageDialog.findViewById(R.id.messageView);
  Button okBtn = (Button) messageDialog.findViewById(R.id.messageOkbtn);
  if(okBtn != null){
   okBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
  message.setText(helpText);
  final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mActivity,R.style.ThemeDialogCustom);
  dialog.setContentView(messageDialog);
  dialog.show();
   final Timer t = new Timer();
  t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
     @Override
   public void run() {
   if(dialog.isShowing()){
    dialog.dismiss();
   }
   t.cancel();
   }
   },mSec);
   }
   });
  }
 }
```

[For referance](http://www.androidsourcehelp.com/2013/10/android-customized-toast-messageusing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sets toast to a specific period in milli-seconds:

```
public void toast(int millisec, String msg) {
    Handler handler = null;
    final Toast[] toasts = new Toast[1];
    for(int i = 0; i < millisec; i+=2000) {
        toasts[0] = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toasts[0].show();
        if(handler == null) {
            handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    toasts[0].cancel();
                }
            }, millisec);
        }
    }
}
```