# How to dismiss a toast message before the provided time to display it

Tags: android, android-toast

**What i have is a simple toast message that stays dispalayed until 90seconds are completed:**

```
Toast.makeText(ActAtomicGodImages.this, "Please Wait \n Song is buffering ...", 90000);
```

**What i am trying to do:**

1. Say i have a button click listener what does some action(Ex: opens
   another activity).
2. On click of that button i want to dismiss the toast even if the
   90seconds are not completed
3. Is this possible, if so how

Comment: Why not use a progress bar instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Call `cancel()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#cancel()) on the `Toast` to get rid of it.

However, 90000 will not work. Your choices are `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` or `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`, neither of which are anywhere near 90 seconds in duration.

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this:

1. Define your toast, possibly like this, maybe as a global variable in your class, so you can access it from anywhere in your class:

   ```
   Toast toast = new Toast(context);
   ```
2. To show it

   ```
   toast.setText("Text");
   toast.show(); //(call show()  to display Toast)
   ```
3. When you need to hide it:

   ```
   toast.cancel();//(call cancel() to  hide Toast).
   ```

Also note that a duration of 90000 may not work correctly, as CommonsWare says.

Comment: [+1] for descriptive answer .... apart from the two values `short` and `long` its not possible to give any other values  (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2221285/1083093)

Comment: Great answer but actually, you have to create the toast object like this,  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  or your app crashes.