# Cancel toast message on touch

Tags: android, android-toast

I'm trying to make my toast message disappear prematurely when the background is touched. The toast should disappear when every part of the screen is touched... I know the method is .cancel but I can't utilize it properly.. this is what I tried:

I tried with the .setontouchlistener method but it doesn't work... I'm new in android development so it would be appreciated to have a sample code to learn from... I'll show you my code, this is it:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private RelativeLayout relalayout
private LinearLayout linelayout;
private ScrollView scrollayout;
public Toast toast;
private ImageView backgroundimg;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activitymain);
    Bundle extradata1 = getIntent().getExtras();
    String textString = extradata1.getString("ImportedData");
    TextView mytext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    relalayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relalayout);
    linelayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linelayout);
    scrollayout = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrolllayout);
    backgroundimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    toast = new Toast(this);

 if (textString.equals("firstimported")) {

        String mytxt = "";
        StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.firsttext);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));


        try {

            while ((mytxt = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sbuffer.append(mytxt + "\n");

            }

            mytext.setText(sbuffer);
            is.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String text = sbuffer.toString();
        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text);

ClickableSpan clickspan1 = new ClickableSpan() {
@Override
public void onClick(View widget) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "this is the toast",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();}
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {

        super.updateDrawState(ds);
        ds.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        ds.setUnderlineText(false);}
    };

    scrollayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        toast.cancel();
        return false;
    }
});
ss.setSpan(clickspan1, 52, 53, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

mytext.setText(ss);
        mytext.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

}
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

the activity crashes when I touch the screen.. so it just won't work.

Comment: where you initialize `toast` object?

Comment: You are right here I don't initialize it.. let me edit it...

Comment: Now it's edited.. but what happens is.. the scrollbar stops working.. I think the method is wrong, maybe I should call another layout in the ontouch method??

Comment: What u did is created a `toast` variable inside of your onClick method. Define that variable over your activity then only it will be available in other methods of the same activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Toast toast; 
@Override
public void onClick(View widget) {
    toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "this is the toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
scrollayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(toast != null)
            toast.cancel();
        return super.onTouch(v, event);
    }
});
```

---

Update Answer as per the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ScrollView scrollayout;
    public Toast toast;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activitymain);
        TextView mytext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        scrollayout = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrolllayout);
        StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
        sbuffer.append("1234567890\n");
        sbuffer.append("1234567890\n");
        sbuffer.append("1234567890\n");
        sbuffer.append("1234567890\n");
        sbuffer.append("1234567890\n");
        sbuffer.append("1234567890\n");
        sbuffer.append("1234567890\n");
        sbuffer.append("1234567890\n");
        sbuffer.append("1234567890\n");
        sbuffer.append("1234567890\n");
        String text = sbuffer.toString();
        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text);
        ClickableSpan clickspan1 = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "this is the toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                super.updateDrawState(ds);
                ds.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                ds.setUnderlineText(false);
            }
        };
        scrollayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (toast != null) {
                    toast.cancel();
                    toast = null;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        ss.setSpan(clickspan1, 52, 53, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        mytext.setText(ss);
        mytext.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }
}
```

I have changed some values that you used as I didn't have all the resources, But major change you need to do is in the ClickSpan initialization and scrolllayout touch event. Please compare them. 
I got the following output with scrolling after the toast has been shown.
[image]

Applogies for the long size gif.

Comment: it doesn't work if I do this the scrollbar stops moving.

Comment: Do you have any other layout over your scrollLayout?

Comment: @user8467834 Can you try with `return true;` inside your `onTouch` method or `return super.onTouch(v, event);`

Comment: the xml file is composed by: RelativeLayout, background image, Scrolllayout with inside it a RelativeLayout and a Textview.

Comment: have you tried with the change of the return value of the onTouch method. Caz i think that with `return super.onTouch(v, event);` your scrollLayout won't stop scrolling.

Comment: it gives me errors, but return MainActivity.super.onTouchEvent(event). prevents it from stopping. The problem is it doesn't actually make the toast disappear after the bar is touched.. :(

Comment: It won't be `return MainActivity.super.onTouchEvent(event)`, it will be `return super.onTouch(v, event);`. Check in the edited answer

Comment: cannot resolve method onTouch(android.view.View, android.view.MotionEvent)'

Comment: can you please edit all your code? So I can check it. Whatever that class file is.

Comment: I edited it I put most of the code hope it's more understandable now

Comment: @user8467834 Please check the updated answer. I found mistakes in your code and have corrected it. I have kept the code only which is necessary for the demo purpose. Please use only suitable code. The major part you need to check is in the ClickSpan and OnTouchListener.  Just follow the answer and you'll get your solution. Also I have attached a gif of the output which is showing toast being cancelled as soon as i start scrolling.

Comment: You're great! That's right, it's working now, thanks a lot!!! I set your answer as corrected and upvoted :)

Comment: Do you think there is a way to further implement a CountDownTimer to this code without the App crashing to show the toast for longer time??......... like in 
 Regis_AG answer of this question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220560/can-an-android-toast-be-longer-than-toast-length-long

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare the `Toast` object on your activity's variable

```
private Toast toast;
```

And then initialize it on your onClick method:

```
toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "this is the toast",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

Also, on your `onTouch` you should check if the toast object is nul:

```
if(toast != null){
   toast.cancel();
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work if I do this the scrollbar stops moving,

Comment: Maybe the problem is in calling scrollayout, I should make a layout out of the toast?..

Answer (score 0):

Toast.makeText returns a Toast object. Call cancel() on this object to cancel it.

Comment: How do you do that? I call the object "toast" if I do Toast toast =Toast.maketext etc... but it still doesn't work.

Comment: you need initialize toast as well