# How to Show Toast for a certain time

Tags: android, android-toast

Android Toast can be Set for a certain time without using Toast.LENGTH_LONG or Toast.LENGTH_SHORT.

That can be achieved with very simple Code:

```
private void customToast{
 long delayTimeForToast = 3500 //3.5sec

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your TEXT", (int)toastDelayTime).show();
}
```

That Toast can visible for 3.5 sec

Comment: If this is just matter of a Alert you can use `SnackBar` or a `AlertDialog`..

Answer (score 0):

Try this reference from page [show a Toast for a specific duration](https://blog.cindypotvin.com/toast-specific-duration-android/)

```
private Toast mToastToShow;
public void showToast(View view) {
    // Set the toast and duration
    int toastDurationInMilliSeconds = 10000;
    mToastToShow = Toast.makeText(this, "Hello world, I am a toast.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

   // Set the countdown to display the toast
    CountDownTimer toastCountDown;
   toastCountDown = new CountDownTimer(toastDurationInMilliSeconds, 1000 /*Tick duration*/) {
          public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
          mToastToShow.show();
      }
      public void onFinish() {
         mToastToShow.cancel();
         }
    };

    // Show the toast and starts the countdown
    mToastToShow.show();
    toastCountDown.start();
}
```

Comment: In my method, I don't need to call Countdown Time. "delayTimeForToast" can use for that, just change the value

Comment: This will not work and not recommended at all .This will pop up a new Toast each time and in some Devices toast message appear with animation so.... ..

Comment: Just a copy/paste answer of https://stackoverflow.com/a/49500953/9248098 .

Comment: @GowthamKK I tried it and working in my case thats y posted

Comment: It is working @ADM

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your answer.

Comment: you should give proper credit in copy pasted answers @TejpalBh