# Toast message remain for long time

Tags: java, android

I want to show Toast when no results found after searching ,
I made a simple Toast but toast remains for long time and i want it to disappear after short time

this is code

```
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            final String[] dose = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.doses);
            final String[] use = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.uses);
            final String[] composition = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.composition);
            
            final TypedArray img  = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.img);
            for (String search : suggestions)
            {
                if (query.equals(search)){

                    for (int i =0; i<suggestions.length; i++){

                        if (query.equals(suggestions[i])){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,productDetails.class);

                            int im = img.getResourceId(i,-1);

                            intent.putExtra("img",im);

                            intent.putExtra("dose",dose[i]);
                            intent.putExtra("use",use[i]);
                            intent.putExtra("composition",composition[i]);
                            intent.putExtra("title",suggestions[i].toUpperCase());

                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        }
                }
              else if (query!= search){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Results Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    
                }

            }

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2220560/1499877 you cannot define a custom duration for Toast.makeText. `Toast. LENGTH_SHORT` is the `0` flag, and `Toast. LENGTH_LONG` is the `1` flag.

Comment: I would recommend trying to indent your code properly, then it would make it much easier to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Your toast is showing in for loop, he is added to queue multiple time, remove it from loop

Comment: if I removed it from for loop   (string search : suggestions)   , search not resolved and  become in red color 
so how to remove it from loop ?

Comment: Bad practices, you can collect all search in array, and show one time

Comment: String notFound= StringUtils.join(listNotFouns, ", "); Show in toast notFound variable outside of loop

Comment: I am beginner and really I donnot know how to solve this problem

Comment: ArrayList notFound = new ArrayList<String>(); for...else if (query!= search){
                   notFound.add(search);
                    
                } and outside of loop  String notFoundJoined = StringUtils(notFound, ", "); Toaste.makeText(context, notFoundJouned...

Comment: thanks for reply,
but how to use StringUtilis?

Comment: Use TextUtils.join(", ", notFound);

Comment: when i did that and remove toast from loop,
it was shown on the screen even the search meet the suggestion and open it's activity